# Android-java Fil transfer over TCP byte missing

Tags: sockets, missing-data

sending side- It is in android and it is part of AsyncTask, doInBackground. Basically, it will send file name, size, and image data to serverside.

```
                InetAddress serverIP = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
                Socket client = new Socket(serverIP,SERVER_PORT);
                System.out.println("Connected to Server\n");
                System.out.println(imgFile.length());
                //sending name of the file
                PrintWriter name = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()),true);
                name.println(fileName);
                name.flush();
                //sending size of the file
                name.println(imgFile.length());
                name.flush();

                //sending body
                DataInputStream imgBodyIn = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(imgFile));
                DataOutputStream imgBodyOut = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int len;
                long filesize = imgFile.length();
                while(filesize >=0&& (len=imgBodyIn.read(buffer,0,(int)Math.min(buffer.length,filesize)))>0){
                    imgBodyOut.write(buffer,0,len);
                    filesize-=len;
                }
                name.close();
                imgBodyIn.close();
                imgBodyOut.flush();
                imgBodyOut.close(); 
                client.close();
```

Receiving side

```
          //receiving name
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));             
          String name = in.readLine();
          System.out.println("Name of the File : " + name+".JPG");
          //receiveing size info
          String size = in.readLine();
          System.out.println("Size of the File :"+size +"bytes");

          //storing file
          File f = new File("/home/ubuntu", name+".JPG");
          FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f);

          int len=0;
          long received=0;
          byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER];
        while(received<=Long.parseLong(size)&&(len=sock.getInputStream().read(buf))>0)
         {  

            output.write(buf,0,len);
            received +=len;
            System.out.print("Receiving.."+received +"/"+size+"\r");


         }    
         output.flush();
         output.close();
         in.close();
         System.out.println("\n"+name+".JPG received");
         System.out.println("Size received :"+f.length()+"bytes");
```

when I tried to send a file, correct size info and name are transferred. However, I could not receive full file; some bytes are missing. Buffer size I am using is 1024.

Sample run :

```
 Waiting for client to connect..
Client Accepted

Name of the File : P1011474.JPG
Size of the File :714438bytes
Receiving..712997/714438
P1011474.JPG received
Size received :712997bytes

socket closed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's the `BufferedReader` on the receiving side, which contains an internal buffer to improve performance when reading from the stream. See [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html):

> Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.

So it won't just read the two lines, but might as well **read ahead** after your two lines. Therefore a part of the binary image you appended might be buffered as well. When you then try to read the binary data directly from the `InputStream` wrapped with `DataInputStream`, you won't receive the bytes which were already buffered in the `BufferedReader` instance.

I would suggest, that you don't use a `PrintWriter` but instead write the file name and length directly using methods from `DataOutputStream`, e.g.:

```
out.writeUTF(fileName);
out.writeLong(imgFile.length());
```

On the receiving side use the `read*` methods of `DataInputStream`, instead of the `BufferedReader`. If you want to buffer, wrap the socket `InputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream`:

```
 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(
     new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
 String fileName = dis.readUTF();
 long fileLength = dis.readLong();
 // now read file contents from stream
```

And by the way, you don't have to do:

```
imgBodyIn.read(buffer,0,(int)Math.min(buffer.length,filesize))
```

when reading in the image from a file, just do:

```
 imgBodyIn.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)
```

The end of stream/file is recognized and `read()` will return the length of bytes read, so you don't need to do `Math.min()`.

Comment: I am sorry but could you explain in detail ? Thank you.

Comment: @user2543738: I improved the explanation, if you have concrete questions, please ask.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation, I did change to above method both sender and receiver side but still receiving same amount(showed in thread).

Comment: I checked and the front part of image part is somewhat different from original.

Comment: Solved! by removing BufferedInputStream! Thank you!